# Replace the top level object in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have an interface named `UIState` defined as:

```
interface UIState {
    comment1: string;
    comment2: string;
    title: {
        data: string;
    };
    // ... other properties ...
}
```

I fetch data from the backend server.

I want is to replace top-level properties of the current state with corresponding properties from the fetched state, if they exist in the fetched state. If a property doesn't exist in the fetched state, I want to retain the current state's property value.

Here is the code I tried.
The current state is saved in variable `prevState` and the fetched state is save in `fetchedUIState`.

```
type Mutable<Type> = {
    -readonly [Key in keyof Type]: Type[Key];
};

let newState: Mutable<UIState> = { ...prevState };

// Iterate over keys from fetchedUIState and replace in newState
(Object.keys(fetchedUIState) as Array<OverlappingKeys<UIState, typeof fetchedUIState>>).forEach(key => {
     if (typeof newState[key] === typeof fetchedUIState[key]) {
      newState[key] = fetchedUIState[key] as UIState[typeof key];
       }
    });
```

But TypeScript throws an error:

```
Type 'string | { data: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string & { data: string; }'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & { data: string; }'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ data: string; }'.
```

This happens because TypeScript isn't able to guarantee that the type of `fetchedUIState[key]` will always match the type of `newState[key]`. How can I ensure type safety in this scenario without resorting to the any type?